# Launch excel.exe on Jenkins CI

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

this below python command works normally to open an excel file when using IDE

> > import os
> >     os.system('start excel.exe FILE.xlsx')

but after implementing on Jenkins CI, it did not give me any output!
so, i would like to know how to launch excel.exe on Jenkins CI ?

Comment: What OS is your Jenkins running on? It probably launched, but in session 0

Comment: @Slav: Running on Windows7, and is it possible to display the output which is running in the session 0 ?

Comment: Actually, session 0 is [isolated in Windows 7](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: my answer is here [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci/22610664#22610664)