# Open Excel on Jenkins CI

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am working on Windows 7 (logged in as session no.1), my Jenkins CI is running as windows service in session 0.
My problem is.. I want to open an Excel file through Jenkins CI in session 0, but want to display its GUI on session 1.

I know that session 0 is isolated in Windows 7, but is it possible to run a process in session 0 and then output in another session? please help.

Comment: I modified my whole answer after I got it to work on Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**
Took a little trial and error, but this is what finally worked for me (Windows 7 64-bit).

- Download [**PsTools**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from Microsoft site
- We only need `psexec.exe`, but you can extract everything. Extract to some location accessible by Jenkins, preferably without spaces in the path.
- Open elevated command prompt: type `cmd` into Start's quicksearch, right click `cmd.exe`, select `Run as Administrator`.
- Type `C:\path\to\psexec.exe -accepteula` and press enter.
- Type `C:\path\to\psexec.exe -i 1 cmd` and press enter. (If you see a command prompt appear, all is good, close it now)
- In Job configuration, configure **Execute Windows Batch command** step
- Write the following:
  `C:\path\to\psexec.exe -accepteula && C:\path\to\psexec.exe -i 1 cmd /c start C:\PROGRA~2\MICROSO~1\path\to\excel.exe`

Where:

- `C:\path\to` is your full path to `psexec.exe`, unless it is in your `%path%`
- `-i 1` is the session ID that you want to launch in.
- `C:\PROGRA~2\MICROSO~1\path\to` is your full path to `excel.exe` **without spaces**. Since most Office installations are going to be under paths with spaces, like "Program Files (x86), you have to figure out the short path, or place it somewhere without spaces.
- Having `excel.exe` under `%path%` and working from regular command line **was not enough**.

A little explanation for those that care:

- `psexec` needs to install a services first. For that, it needs to be run from elevated command prompt for the first time. This is a one-time installation step.
- To make `psexec` work, you need to accept the EULA prompt. This is done per session/user. So even if you run `psexec -accepteula` in your command prompt, it doesn't help when Jenkins service (running as Local System in session 0) tries to use it. Therefore, you have to place that into the Jenkins job, along with the command. Technically, it only needs to be there once, and can be removed afterwards, but it definitely doesn't hurt to keep it there.
- I've used `cmd /k` and running this command from my local cmd prompt to debug. This is what made me realize I couldn't find a way to escape the spaces (tried various quoting), so had to resort to short file names. Note that short file names are not required, this is just to escape spaces.

Answer (score 0):

no its not-

plus any UI interactions requires you to run Jenkins as Java web start rather than a service or you can not interact with UI elements.

Comment: You can right-click on service `Properties`, get to `Log On` tab, and check `Allow service to interact with desktop`