# How to run jenkins job as a system user?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

- Rightnow, my jenkins jobs are run by `Tomcat Server use`r.
- I wanted it to run as User `'Admin'`, so i tried creating a slave and
  added my same jenkins machine as the slave.
- I have also added this as a `windows service`, and have confiured the
  **Admin user/pwd** in the Logon Tab.
- But still, when i run a job which executes the UI tests, i'm not able
  to see them running in the firefox but it runs and the screenshots
  are captured!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to have Jenkins spawn a process in your session that you can see at the monitor?

Have a look here: [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci/22610664#22610664), replace excel with whatever you are launching.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jenkins as windows service, it won't allow GUI execution.

It only allows backgound running jobs.

If you want run UI test then stop your jenkins service , use some other way to connect your slave.