# Jenkins task to switch on monitor if it's switched off

Tags: batch-file, ant, jenkins

I use Jenkins to run our builds. What I want to do is to wakeup the monitor before build starts. This is what I have done so far.

Use nircmdc.exe (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and prepare a batch file to turn on monitor. I have tested the script through command prompt and it works fine.

Then I add a build step in Jenkins to execute windows batch file before running the ANT script. Then I remote start the build (via URL). Console shows that the batch file is being executed. But the monitors doesn't wake up.

Then I included a target in ANT to execute the same batch file and tested running the ANT via CMD. This wakes up the monitor and continue with the build steps.

But, if I run this ant script from Jenkins, everything works fine except waking up the monitor.

Is this something to do with privileges ?

Has someone done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think I've ever heard of a requirement to wake up the monitor, so probably no one has done anything like this.

However, your problem is probably due to Jenkins process running in a separate session from your machine's console. Have a look at my answer here: **[Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci)**, it explains how to get around the session issue.