# Running exe files with Hudson on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows, hudson

I am attempting to have a Hudson job run a windows executable on a Windows 8 VM.  When I attempt to run the exe file I get the error:

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\hudson\workspace\workspaceName\installer\bin\fileToExecute.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation`

Has anyone run into this and had it run automatically?  I can't just have the exe file on the VM and set its permissions because a new copy gets downloaded at the start of each build.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have not tried this with Windows 8.

First things first, even if you succeed to launch an .exe application from Hudson/Jenkins, it will be running under a different session, probably invisible to you. I've managed to achieve the workarounds for this with `PsExec` as detailed here:

**[Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci)**

With the above method, you will be able to launch an application and actually *see it* in the logged in session.

If your application **does** require elevated permissions for whatever reason, you've got to add `-h` switch to `PsExec`