# How to open visual studio on a machine using jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I was trying to open visual studio on a machine using jenkins, but he process is running on background only, the studio window is not active/ visible to the user.

I  was trying to execute Scaffolding commands on Visual studio Package manager console using AutoHotKey exe.

Is there any way to do this.. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer on explanation how to open an `exe` in session 1 of the master server [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci)

Comment: E:\Jenkins>exit -1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Collecting metadata...
Metadata collection done.
Finished: FAILURE