# Can Jenkins run executable files called through a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have to install a program on a Windows 8 server using Jenkins as a framework. I wrote a PowerShell script that does run and install executable files when run through the PowerShell console. This does not happen when I run the same scripts through Jenkins.

Nothing happens except the text I output does appear on Jenkins' console.

Can running an .exe be done on Jenkins through a PowerShell script? Please help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Read a similar answer here:
[Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci)

The issue is that Jenkins on Windows usually runs in "Session 0". Which is not visible to the logged in user. The trick is to launch the process (Excel in that answer, PowerShell in your case) in session 1.