# Open Excel With Batch

Tags: windows, excel, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I am trying to open an excel file for processing using batch. The code I run on batch is correctly opening the file. The problem is when I try to trigger the same batch file remotely using Jenkins(I have a windows slave). The Jenkins job gets stuck infinitely there after running the command. It does nothing, just shows a message on the screen that says: "A program running on this computer is trying to display a message."[can't post image because of low reputation],
and nothing more.

On clicking view message you get a message that Excel cannot open this file because of the following reasons. which is, i know nothing but a false alarm. How can I modify batch command or Jenkins job or something else on the virtual machine to make the code run?

This is my current command:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL" /r "C:\file_name.xlsm"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci)

Comment: Already tried. not working.

Comment: @slav: your article was useful, I learnt about sessions in windows, but it didn't solve any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to create a folder named "Desktop" in system32 and SysWow64 (windows 7 64 bit)
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile

so the full path will be:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

IIf this doesn't work, you can check the solution by Slav: [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci).
it pointed me in the right direction