# Execute file from Jenkins Job : allow job to interact with desktop

Tags: windows, excel, jenkins

I'm sorry if this question has already been posted but i have a problem to execute an xlsm file from Jenkins Job with the Execute Batch Command.

I've tried this "C:...\myfile.xlsm" it doesn't seem to work. So i've made some research and found this topic : [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci/22610664#22610664)

However, when i put the command with -accepteula, i have this message : 
*This program is blocked by a group policy. For more information, contact your system adminitrator.*

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did you contact system admin?

Comment: From the question you linked-   are trying to allow jenkins to interact with  GUI session? Running jenkins slave as "a program on desktop" (JNLP) will help.

Comment: It worked !
Jenkins was running as a Windows Service, but when it's not, the previous command "C:...\myfile.xlsm" in Execute Batch Command works fine ! 
Thank you Jayan !

Comment: :).  I provided it as answer for future :)

Answer (score 0):

From the question you linked- It looks like you want to  allow jenkins to interact with GUI session

Running jenkins slave as "a program on desktop" (JNLP) will help.